# In ZFC, do we use the set $\mathbb{N}$ in the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ recursively?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, natural-numbers

In ZFC set theory, we define the set of the natural numbers as follows: By the axiom of infinity, an inductive set exists. Let I be an inductive set. Then, $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as $\{ x\in I |\forall J \:(J\; is \;inductive \rightarrow x\in J)\}$ or in some books it is even defined as $\{ x|\forall J \:(J\; is \;inductive \rightarrow x\in J)\}$. It feels to me that this definition is recursive and therefore it is kind of a logical fallacy. Here is my argument:

Let us accept the first one as our definition of $\mathbb{N}$. Then, I am asking myself that “Is $1$ in $\mathbb{N}$?”. Then, I should check whether the sentence $\forall J \:(J\; is \;inductive \rightarrow 1\in J)$ is true or not. According to this sentence we should check whether $1\in J$ for every inductive set $J$. But we know that the set $\mathbb{N}$ is inductive. So, we should also check that whether $1\in \mathbb{N}$ or not. As a result, we get that “In order to know that whether $1\in \mathbb{N}$, we should know first whether $1\in \mathbb{N}$ or not.” This is kind of a contradictive. Isn’t there a self-reference here? Can anyone please what is the problem here, if there is any?

Comment: We may be able to prove that $1$ is in every inductive set via general principles, *without* (even implicitly) checking each specific inductive set separately. And that's exactly what happens here. Just because *some* line of attack is circular doesn't mean that *every* line of attack is circular. That said, you may find the notion of [**(im)predicative definitions**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impredicativity) to be relevant to the general idea here.

Comment: I don't follow.  Why do we need to know that $\mathbb{N}$ is inductive to check whether $1\in J$ for every inductive set $J$?  Seems to me that follows from the definition of the property inductive if you write out the formula for how the property inductive is defined in ZFC.  (I'm ignoring that it's actually 0 not 1.)

Comment: Why do we know $\Bbb N$ is inductive from this definition?

Comment: @Elliot G:  Inductive in ZFC is the formula "$0\epsilon x$ and $\forall y (y \epsilon x \rightarrow (Sy) \epsilon x)$", with $Sy$ shorthand for $y \cup \{y\}$.  From this, it's possible to prove that the definition above implies the $\mathbb{N}$ so defined is inductive.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  I indeed do not intend to show $1$ is in $\mathbb{N}$. It is not my point. I am talking about the definition of $\mathbb{N}$. Non-rigorously speaking, the formula $\phi (x)$  in the definition of $\mathbb{N}$ says something about every inductive set. But $\mathbb{N}$ is also inductive.

Answer (score 1):

In ZFC, inductive(x) is roughly "0 is a member of x, and for all members y of x, the successor of $y$ is also a member of x".
The axiom of infinity says "there exists an inductive set".  Let's call it I.
The definition stated above for $\mathbb{N}$ says roughly "$\mathbb{N}$ is a subset of $I$ which is also the intersection of all inductive sets".
$\mathbb{N}$ so defined is separated out of $I$ by the axiom of separation, because ZFC does not allow for defining arbitrary sets via formulas to avoid the Russell paradox.
It is possible to prove from the definitions that

1. $\mathbb{N}$ itself is inductive.
2. Any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ that is inductive is the whole of $\mathbb{N}$.

I think what confuses you is that 2. is Peano's induction axiom - but notice that is not part of the definitions.  It is a theorem of ZFC that $\mathbb{N}$ satisfies Peano's induction axiom.  There is no recursion in the definition of $\mathbb{N}$.  Just application of ZFC axioms.